# Next without For error when using if else blocks to iterate through a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have no clue.

I tried putting in an End If after each If  then block but obviously that didn't work. Any ideas??

```
Private Sub putCollectionInWorksheet(ByRef ws As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef cData As Collection)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim emp As Employee


    i = 36 ' current row

    For Each emp In cData
        If emp.City = "Dallas" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 31
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
            Next emp


        Else
            If emp.City = "Denver" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = emp.Name
                ws.Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
                ws.Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = vbWhite
                i = i - 1
                 Next emp

        Else

            If emp.City = "Houston" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = emp.Name
                ws.Cells(i, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 52
                ws.Cells(i, 5).Font.Color = vbWhite
                i = i - 1
                 Next emp


        Else

            If emp.City = "Kansas City (Missouri)" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = emp.Name
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 56
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Font.Color = vbWhite
                i = i - 1
                 Next emp


        Else

            If emp.City = "Oklahoma City" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = emp.Name
                ws.Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 47
                ws.Cells(i, 7).Font.Color = vbWhite
                i = i - 1
                 Next emp


        Else

            If emp.City = "Tulsa" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = emp.Name
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
                ws.Cells(i, 8).Font.Color = vbWhite
                i = i - 1
                 Next emp


        End If



End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Right now the rows are like this

Bob | Sue | Ellen | George

Should the collection come across Henry, who is an associate in Dallas, it will just overwrite.

Henry | Sue | Ellen | George

I need it to look like this:

Henry |

Bob  | Sue | Ellen | George

Sorry I can't show a screenshot due to a firewall.

Comment: Birds View: Delete `Next emp` from every where and add it just before the `End Sub` and join your `Else` with `If` to make it `ElSEIF`

Comment: if i do that with elseif, then it wants to be the first statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

This is what I mean from my comments

```
Private Sub putCollectionInWorksheet(ByRef ws As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef cData As Collection)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim emp As Employee

    i = 36 ' current row

    For Each emp In cData
        If emp.City = "Dallas" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 31
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        ElseIf emp.City = "Denver" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        ElseIf emp.City = "Houston" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 52
            ws.Cells(i, 5).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        ElseIf emp.City = "Kansas City (Missouri)" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 56
            ws.Cells(i, 6).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        ElseIf emp.City = "Oklahoma City" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 47
            ws.Cells(i, 7).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        ElseIf emp.City = "Tulsa" And emp.Title = "Associate" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = emp.Name
            ws.Cells(i, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
            ws.Cells(i, 8).Font.Color = vbWhite
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next emp
End Sub
```

Comment: cool that works. I added 'i = 36' within each if block. Is there a way to retain that number in memory so it doesn't just overwrite whatever is at '(i, 3)' etc.?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want the value of i to be constant inside the For loop?

Comment: well if it comes to more than 1 employee that is an associate, it will just overwrite Cell(36, 3) rather than going to Cell(36, 4). It's pulling from a big data sheet and storing all the info in a collection. Employees aren't in any order in the data sheet.

Comment: I am still trying to understand.. few questions. Here is the first What happens if none of the above conditions meet, does the value of `i` still reduce?

Comment: at least one of the above conditions has to be met. data worksheet only has three columsn. name, title, and city.